# Magento Installation - Uable to access Admin panel

Tags: magento

In my localhost i have installed Magento. I can see the Front end, but not the Backend.
When i try to entry wrong username&password to access the backend it throws error message. But when i given valid username & password to access admin, it just remain in the same login page without any error message,

url displayed as

```
http://localhost/magento/index.php/myadmin/index/index/key/3a3f51c8c24d767533889679cd7e85f2/
```

This is my first installation of Magento. is this an installation prob or anything i need to configure??

Comment: in firefox, it got opened. y not in chrome??

Comment: I dont know about this issue properly :P i had this problem with chrome but never attempted to correct it, i just started using firefox :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Firefox instead of Chrome ;) What I know is that by default browsers dont save cookies for localhost, so login does not work in chrome unless u explicitly set cookies for localhost in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

`magento/index.php/admin/index/login/key/`

just add above url to your localhost
Something like this:

```
//localhost/magento/index.php/admin/index/login/key/
```

the key is auto generated so you  don't have to worry about it.